# AEM installation without registration

Tags: installation, aem

I am new to AEM development and trying to learn them on my own interest. Can anyone help me to download the jar files of author and publish without registering in adobe solution partner as i am not working with any company right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to register, AEM is a paid solution, but they can offer you a temporary license to check out the product. And by the way, you will only need a single JAR, since you can configure it to run either in author mode or publish mode. And locally you can run as many instances as you would like.

Comment: But I could not find the temporary license as they are asking for organization email. Can you suggest me any better and easy way other than this registration?

Comment: Just use your personal email or any other email, if you are not working for a company. See the Community Partner here: https://solutionpartners.adobe.com/home.html or call them directly.